# dojox.Grid row background color

Tags: dojo

I have a Grid and I would like to change the background color, do you know how to do it ?

Thanks for your help, have a nice day.

Here is my code :

```
var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url: "..." ?>"});

var model = new dojox.grid.data.DojoData(null,jsonStore,{jsId: 'model', rowsPerPage: 20, query: { date: '*' }});

var view1 = {
        cells: [[
                {name: 'x', width: "80px", field: "date"},
                {name: 'y', width: "50px", field: "weight"},
                {name: 'z', width: "100px", field: "nurse"}
          ]]
};
var layout = [ view1 ];

<div id="gridWeight" dojoType="dojox.Grid" model="model" structure="layout" autoWidth="true" style="height: 150px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `onStyleRow` event or adapt the CSS directly - in your case:

```
.tundra #gridWeight .dojoxGridRow,
.tundra #gridWeight .dojoxGridRowOdd {
    background: red;
}
```